# Find records with same data in multiple fields

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table that defines Departments and Steps for processing products in a manufacturing environment.  Table design is as such:

```
CustPartNum (primary key)
DeptOne
StepOne
DeptTwo
StepTwo
DeptThree
StepThree
...
...
...
DeptTwenty
StepTwenty
```

All fields are Text datatype.

I need to write a query that finds all records where the word "Pack" appears more than once in the Dept fields.  The DeptNUMBER field is essentially a routing.  For instance, DeptOne could be "CM", and StepOne would be the instruction that occurs at that Dept.  I need to find all records that have multiple instances of "Pack" in a Dept field.

I have tried a find duplicates query, but don't believe this is how to achieve result.

Comment: First, i think that you table is a little bit confusing. Using DeptNUMBER is the cause of your problem. Now, i think that You need to right a huge query, counting and gropuing everything ...

Comment: Your question is ambiguous.  Please edit the question to provide sample data and desired results.  Do you mean more than once in a single field?  Do you allow other words in the `dept` fields?  What do you mean?

Comment: @AndreDuarte The DeptNUMBER is used for a chronological workflow/process routing purpose.  I.E. a new product needs to go to DeptOne (for instance, "CM"), for the first step, DeptTwo (for instance, "Pack") as the second step, etc.  Some records may have "Pack" in more than one Dept, and I need to find all records where this is true.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, there are other words in the dept fields, as this field is populated by a dropdown in a form.  "Pack" will not appear more than once in a single field; rather it could appear in multiple different Dept* fields.  That is what I would like to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That table is a bad design, but you could use something like the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT s.*,
    IIf(s.DeptOne = "Pack", 1, 0) AS D1,
    IIf(s.DeptTwo = "Pack", 1, 0) AS D2,
    IIf(s.DeptThree = "Pack", 1, 0) AS D3,
    IIf(s.DeptFour = "Pack", 1, 0) AS D4,
    IIf(s.DeptFive = "Pack", 1, 0) AS D5,
    IIf(s.DeptSix = "Pack", 1, 0) AS D6,
    IIf(s.DeptSeven = "Pack", 1, 0) AS D7,
    IIf(s.DeptEight = "Pack", 1, 0) AS D8,
    IIf(s.DeptNine = "Pack", 1, 0) AS D9,
    IIf(s.DeptTen = "Pack", 1, 0) AS D10,
    IIf(s.DeptEleven = "Pack", 1, 0) AS D11,
    IIf(s.DeptTwelve = "Pack", 1, 0) AS D12,
    IIf(s.DeptThirteen = "Pack", 1, 0) AS D13,
    IIf(s.DeptFourteen = "Pack", 1, 0) AS D14,
    IIf(s.DeptFifteen = "Pack", 1, 0) AS D15,
    IIf(s.DeptSixteen = "Pack", 1, 0) AS D16,
    IIf(s.DeptSeventeen = "Pack", 1, 0) AS D17,
    IIf(s.DeptEightteen = "Pack", 1, 0) AS D18,
    IIf(s.DeptNineteen = "Pack", 1, 0) AS D19,
    IIf(s.DeptTwenty = "Pack", 1, 0) AS D20
FROM MyTable s
) m
WHERE (m.D1 + m.D2 + m.D3 + m.D4 + m.D5 + m.D6 + m.D7 + m.D8 + 
       m.D9 + m.D10 + m.D11 + m.D12 + m.D13 + m.D14 + m.D15 + 
       m.D16 + m.D17 + m.D18 + m.D19 + m.D20) > 1
```

Comment: This worked Linger.  Thank you!  Here is the kicker though, and I am wondering if you can help.  For the query result, I need to change all the the first instances of "PACK" in each record to "PACK-M" and all of the second to "PACK-S"

Comment: I would recommend asking a new question.  You can reference this query in the new question.